# How to get level of fitness of data to a distribution by using probplot() in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matplotlib, python-2.7, probability

I have 2 sets of data of float numbers, set A and set B. Both of them are matrices of size 40*40. I would like to find out which set is closer to the normal distribution. I know how to use probplot() in matlab to plot the probability of one set. However, I do not know how to find out the level of the fitness of the distribution is.

In python, when people use problot, a parameter ,R^2, shows how good the distribution of the data is against to the normal distribution. The closer the R^2 value to value 1, the better the fitness is. Thus, I can simply use the function to compare two set of data by their R^2 value. However, because of some machine problem, I can not use the python in my current machine. Is there such parameter or function similar to the R^2 value in matlab ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Do you mean "Normal distribution" or "Multivariate Normal distribution"? I only ask because you state that your matrices are 40 by 40.

Comment: I meant just a Normal distribution not Multivariate Normal Distribution. I do not know what multivariate normal distribution is yet. Bot set A and B are just two matrices of numerical numbers such as 0.121..etc. I first take all contents from the matrices and put them into 2 one-dimensional vectors for set A and B correspondingly. Then, I just applied probplot() function. It is not supposed to be a complicated problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fitting a curve or surface to data and obtaining the goodness of fit, i.e.,  sse, rsquare, dfe, adjrsquare, rmse, can be done using the function `fit`.  [More info here.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html)..

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand what y is for the fit function. In addition, it does not have normal distribution. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

The approach of @nate (+1) is definitely one possible way of going about this problem. However, the statistician in me is compelled to suggest the following alternative (that does, alas, require the statistics toolbox - but you have this if you have the student version):

Given that your data is Normal (not Multivariate normal), consider using the [Jarque-Bera](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/stats/jbtest.html) test.

Jarque-Bera tests the null hypothesis that a given dataset is generated by a Normal distribution, versus the alternative that it is generated by some other distribution. If the Jarque-Bera test statistic is less than some critical value, then we fail to reject the null hypothesis.

So how does this help with the goodness-of-fit problem? Well, the larger the test statistic, the more "non-Normal" the data is. The smaller the test statistic, the more "Normal" the data is.

So, assuming you have converted your matrices into two vectors, `A` and `B` (each should be 1600 by 1 based on the dimensions you provide in the question), you could do the following:

```
%# Build sample data
A = randn(1600, 1);
B = rand(1600, 1);

%# Perform JB test
[ANormal, ~, AStat] = jbtest(A);
[BNormal, ~, BStat] = jbtest(B);

%# Display result
if AStat < BStat
    disp('A is closer to normal'); 
else
    disp('B is closer to normal');
end
```

As a little bonus of doing things this way, `ANormal` and `BNormal` tell you whether you can reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis that the sample in `A` or `B` comes from a normal distribution! Specifically, if `ANormal` is 1, then you fail to reject the null (ie the test statistic indicates that `A` is probably drawn from a Normal). If `ANormal` is 0, then the data in `A` is probably not generated from a Normal distribution.

**CAUTION:** The approach I've advocated here is only valid if `A` and `B` are the same size, but you've indicated in the question that they are :-)

Comment: Very clear explanation! Thank you very much and I learn a lot. Sorry that I didn't describe clearly. A and B are not the same size. Still very grateful for your input.

Comment: @Cassie No worries - there is probably a way to adjust the statistics so that valid comparison of different size `A` and `B` can be performed, but I'd have to do a fair bit of research myself to work that one out, so probably best to go with nate's solution :-)